# Someone try to hack my site, want to understand the log

Tags: hacking

I have a wordpress site hosted on CentOS 6. After see the following access log, I checked the server, it seems ok. Can anyone explain what does this guy trying to do? Did they get what they want?

I have disabled allow_url_include, and restricted open_basedir to web dir and tmp(/etc is not in the path).

`190.26.208.130 - - [05/Sep/2012:21:24:42 -0700] "POST http://my_ip/?-d%20allow_url_include%3DOn+-d%20auto_prepend_file%3D../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00%20-n/?-d%20allow_url_include%3DOn+-d%20auto_prepend_file%3D../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00%20-n HTTP/1.1" 200 32656 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read the article. From my understanding, the hacker was trying to add something to my file from a remote link. I doubt it's successful since the allow_url_include function is disabled.

Comment: Is a content length of `32656` normal for the content served by `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [CVE-2012-1823](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1823) first.

The above URL is decoded as:

`http://my_ip/?-d allow_url_include=On+-d auto_prepend_file=../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd� -n/?-d allow_url_include=On+-d auto_prepend_file=../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd� -n`

`?-d allow_url_include=On`: he is trying to add an extra parameter in the php-cgi call:

```
$ php-cgi -h
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
```

`+-d auto_prepend_file=../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd� -n`: then prepend his file as code to execute. Don't know why he uses Path Traversal attack here instead of using his code or [`php://input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

`-n` at the end to negate the `php.ini`:

```
$ php-cgi -h
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
```

PS: No need to worry if you aren't running PHP as a CGI script.

Comment: What is a simple way to test if you are running PHP as CGI script?